# Exclude trash from save_post

Tags: actions, save-post, trash

I have a function which processes custom metabox data on saving my custom post type:

```
add_action('save_post_customtypehere','myown_save_customtype_fn');
function myown_save_customtype_fn($ID) { ... }
```

However, the function also runs when I trash items within this CPT (I guess it's effectively saving the post to change `post_status` to `trash`).  Without the metabox being present, my function ends up clearing things like `post_name` (not great if I need to restore from trash!).

I have two thoughts but can't quite get across the finishing line with them:

1) In order to update post data I use `remove_action()` and `add_action()` again around `wp_update_post(array('post_key'=>$sanitized_form_input))` - as per the codex instructions, this is required to avoid an infinite loop.  Could there be a similar way of excluding from a trash_post action (I already tried `remove_action('trash_post','myown_save_customtype_fn'` immediately after the original `add_action` line).

2) Is there something I can use in a conditional within `myown_save_customtype_fn` (along the lines of `if (current action!='trash_post') { ...`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) gets fired, once the post is saved. We get the current post object as the second parameter. So we can check, if the current post status is trash:

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', function( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    if ( 'trash' === $post->post_status ) {
        return;
    }

    /** do your stuff **/
}, 10, 3 );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following helps for skipping the restore option as well as the trash option:

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post_POSTTYPEHERE', function( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    
    /* do not save meta on trash/untrash event */
    if(
        isset($_REQUEST['action']) &&
        ( $_REQUEST['action'] == 'trash' || $_REQUEST['action'] == 'untrash')
    ){
        return;
    }

    /** do your stuff **/
    
}, 10, 3 );
?>
```